# Javafx: How to group mouse actions over an image

Tags: java, javafx

I am a newbie in Javafx and I am trying to fix a cropping over an image. I found an interesting solution for cropping with [rubber band](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994313/2688419) and now I try to modified this in my scenario.
I have two controllers. One controller has the crop button (CropController) and another controller which contain an image as ImageController.

CropController:

```
public class CropController {

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {}

    @FXML
    private void handleCrop(){
    }

}
```

ImageController:

```
public class ImageController {

    @FXML
    private ImageView MainImage;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        modelSharedOne.imageProperty()
        .addListener((obs, oldImage,newImage)-> MainImage.setImage(newImage));
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleMousePresses(){}

    @FXML
    private void handleMouseDragged(){}

    @FXML
    private void handleMouseReleased(){}

}
```

Based on the rubber band solution I need to group those three mouse handlers. I do not know what could be the best solution for this. I have tried many solutions like creating a model between these two controllers but I have not managed to solve this solution.
Anyone knows how can I solve this?

My current solution

CropController:

```
public class ToolboxController {

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

    }

    @FXML
    private void handleCrop(){

        SharedModelTwo.callHandlerInWorkstation();
    }
}
```

SharedModelTwo:

```
public class CropImageModel {

ImageController imageController;

    public void callHandlerInImage(){

        imageController = new ImageController();
        imageController.handleCrop();
    }

}
```

ImageController:

```
public class ImageController {

    @FXML
    private ImageView MainImage;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        modelSharedOne.imageProperty()
            .addListener((obs, oldImage,newImage)-> MainImage.setImage(newImage));
    }

    public void handleCrop() {
        Image image = getImage();
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        rect = new Rectangle( 0,0,0,0);
        rect.setStroke(Color.BLUE);
        rect.setStrokeWidth(1);
        rect.setStrokeLineCap(StrokeLineCap.ROUND);
        rect.setFill(Color.LIGHTBLUE.deriveColor(0, 1.2, 1, 0.6));

        Group imageLayer = new Group();
        imageLayer.getChildren().add(imageView);
        rubberBandSelection = new RubberBandSelection(imageLayer);
    }
}
```

And rubberBandSelection is a class as it was in the [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30994313/2688419). when I run that it does not hit when mouse pressed on image.

Comment: Did you try to make a class that has a method like a `public static void handleEvent (javafx.event.Event event)` and pass to it all events from a controllers?

Comment: @Mr.RitMakston I am not sure about your question :(  but I have updated the question with my solution.