# JavaFX How to crop image once for multiple aspect ratios

Tags: image, javafx

I'm creating a desktop application in JavaFX which enables the user to search for people in different categories. There is a screen which shows each category as a tile with an image (Aspect ratio 1:1). When you click on a tile it opens another page and the image from the tile should now be displayed as the background image (Aspect ratio 16:9). The images are selected by an admin user, so it must be cropped because it could be too large, have a wrong aspect ratio and so on.

I wonder how to set up an easy way to enable the admin user to select the picture he wants, without having to crop the image twice (once as 1:1 and once as 16:9). I thought about crop only to 1:1 and then for displaying as 16:9 just zooming the picture, but this leads to bad quality if the resolution isn't high enough.

For cropping I'm referencing to this post from Roland:
[How to make a Javafx Image Crop App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993681/how-to-make-a-javafx-image-crop-app/30994313)

Comment: It seems you could use two images. One for the tile and a different one for the background. The background one you can edit using some photo editing program.

Answer (score 0):

For background images you can simply specify that the image should cover the `Region`.

`ImageView` allows you to specify a [`viewport`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html#viewportProperty) allowing you to specify the region of the `Image` that should be displayed. If chosen accordingly this does the croping for you.

The following code uses the same ratio for both for simplicity's sake:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final Image image = new Image(URL);

    // size to use for both nodes
    double targetHeight = 400;
    double targetWidth = targetHeight * 16 / 9;

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
    imageView.setFitWidth(targetWidth);
    imageView.setFitHeight(targetHeight);

    // calculate viewport
    imageView.setViewport((image.getHeight() / targetHeight < image.getWidth() / targetWidth)
            ? new Rectangle2D(0, 0, image.getHeight() / targetHeight * targetWidth, image.getHeight())
            : new Rectangle2D(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getWidth() / targetWidth * targetHeight));

    Region backgroundRegion = new Region();
    backgroundRegion.setPrefSize(targetWidth, targetHeight);
    backgroundRegion.setBackground(new Background(
            new BackgroundImage(
                    image,
                    BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                    BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT,
                    BackgroundPosition.CENTER,
                    new BackgroundSize(0, 0, false, false, false, true) // cover
            )));

    HBox root = new HBox(imageView, backgroundRegion);
    root.setFillHeight(false);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(20));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```